# How to flush all the DHCP leases with virsh. So all not just one with net-update default delete ip-dhcp-host

Tags: fedora, kvm, dhcp, virsh

OS: Fedora 28
KVM

So I am trying to delete all the dhcp leases with virsh, so all of them at once not one by one or any one in particular. I know that you can use net-update default delete ip-dhcp-host (this is not a full command) to delete a particular entry, but I want to delete all of them.

Comment: This method works for me. cat /dev/null > /var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/virbr0.status

Comment: `cat /dev/null > file` is more efficiently written `> file`. In both cases the shell truncates the file, but in the first you have to actually run the cat program which has to open /dev/null, as well as having to type more.